# meteor js unrendered hook?

Tags: javascript, animation, meteor, callback

I like to use Meteor's rendered hook for entrance animations when I'm adding templates.  Here's an example:

in my templates:

```
<template name="main">
    {{#each people}}
        {{>person}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="person">
    <li> {{name}} </li>
</template>
```

in my javascript file:

```
//in js file
Template.person.rendered = function() {
    $(this.firstNode).hide().fadeIn(1500);
}
```

[live example here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/g3j6kNes379rx2ovs)

The question: is there a way to provide an "exit animation" for templates, perhaps using something like an "unrendered" hook?  If not, could one be improvised and wrapped in a package?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Version 0.8.2 Added a special `_uihooks` feature](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/30fb11f1fa0227f1c0ec3eb30b7864ea3b2d210e/History.md#blaze-1)

> Add preliminary API for registering hooks to run when Blaze intends to
>   insert, move, or remove DOM elements. For example, you can use these
>   hooks to animate nodes as they are inserted, moved, or removed. To use
>   them, you can set the _uihooks property on a container DOM element.
>   _uihooks is an object that can have any subset of the following three properties:
>
> insertElement: function (node, next): called when Blaze intends to insert the DOM element node before the element next
>
> moveElement: function (node, next): called when Blaze intends to move the DOM element node before the element next
>
> removeElement: function (node): called when Blaze intends to remove the DOM element node
>
> Note that when you set one of these functions on a container element,
>   Blaze will not do the actual operation; it's your responsibility to
>   actually insert, move, or remove the node (by calling
>   $(node).remove(), for example).

[There's also an example of this in the current todos app](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/c78e04645d970b455c0ef405889242ae9b8e6c47/examples/todos/client/templates/lists-show.js#L20)

For your given example, (it might not work with the sub template, but you can try):

Template:

```
<template name="main">
  <ul>
    {{#each people}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
Template.main.rendered = function(){

  this.find('ul')._uihooks = {
    insertElement: function(node, next) {
      $(node)
        .hide()
        .insertBefore(next)
        .fadeIn();
    },
    removeElement: function(node) {
      $(node).fadeOut(function() {
        this.remove();
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was after.  Going to try it out real quick.

Comment: This is a good enough solution for me!  Thank you, I think this is a really high quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be nice to have a "Template.preDestroyed" hook, but until something like that comes around, it shouldn't be too tricky to just handle it yourself.

You can do something like:

```
$(*template instance selector*).fadeOut( 1500, function(){ $(this).remove(); } )
```

When you want the template instance to leave.

Perhaps it would help if you explained what circumstances are leading to the template being unrendered (and whether that means hidden or removed from the DOM).

Comment: I suppose the ideal solution would take care of exit animations when the template instance in a helper block, like when contained within an `{{#if}}` that is no longer satisfied, or if it disappears from an {{#each}} block.  Maybe you have a list of `people`, and you delete one from the list, triggering the reactive release of the template instance.  It would be really cool if it could fade away using a similar syntax to the `rendered` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Update as of [1.0.4](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#blaze-2) we now have:

- .onRendered
- .onCreated
- .onDestroyed

The old methods have been deprecated.